# Stored Procedure (process data then insert into another table)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What i wana do is actually process some data then insert the processed data into a new table..
but first i need to check the target table ;if empty then delete everything in the table then only insert the fresh processed data..

i'm using sql server 2008...

anyone can give me the sample sql code to create the stored procedure??

Comment: You really need to learn how to ask good questions. Here are some pointers - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Just checked you have asked 7 questions for which you have received 10 answers. But you have not accepted any answer or upvoted any answer. You should upvote/accept answers that are usefull to you.

Comment: good point. This site is all about voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create procedure SprocName
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ProcessedData AS TABLE (IntColumn int, CharColumn varchar(MAX))

  -- get processed data
  INSERT INTO @ProcessedData (IntColumn, CharColumn)
  SELECT IntValue, CharValue FROM SourceTable -- WHERE your condition

  -- check target and delete
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TargetTable)
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TargetTable -- WHERE your condition
  END

  -- insert fresh
  INSERT INTO TargetTable (IntColumn, CharColumn)
  SELECT IntColumn, CharColumn FROM @ProcessedData

END
```

Sorry code not tested ;)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for create stored procedure is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Then you need to do a select, syntax is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Next is an if, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

And finally an insert http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx